# Cost of copying stateless objects (lambdas)?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, functor, stateless

How can one find out if there is a cost in creating an object by copying a lambda?

```
template<typename Lambda>
class A {
public:
  A(Lambda lambda) : _lambda(lambda) {} // const Lambda& lambda less efficient?
  auto call(double x) { return _lambda(x); }
private:
  Lambda _lambda; // is const Lambda& _lambda less efficient?
};
```

I am wondering if having a reference is costly or insignificant (the same as copying the lambda) if the lambda has no state?

Comment: Take a look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: I'd suspect not much more than a function pointer plus the captured variables. If it's completely stateless (no captures) it'll boil down to the function pointer.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Depends what `Lambda` is. If it is the actual anonymous type of a closure, it may not even need a function pointer. The function could be determined strictly from the template argument and it may not even require a function pointer.

Comment: @François Hmm, right. Of cause I was confused and focussed at the regular lambda expression here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References here is going to be ridiculously fragile; you **will** get bugs if you make that a reference.

Lambdas themselves can choose to be nothing but references to external state; just copy them and store them by value.  If there is a performance penalty for this in  a specific use case, the caller can avoid the copy cost.

```
template<class F>
class A {
public:
  explicit A(F f_in) : f(std::move(f_in)) {}
  decltype(auto) call(double x) { return f(x); }
private:
  F f;
};
```

just a few code-quality changes.

Answer (score 1):

> How can one find out if there is a cost in creating an object by copying a lambda?

By testing and profiling with the specific compiler (and switches) you intend to use. Anything else is making assumptions about the quality of an implementation you haven't identified.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple test show that simple lambda is empty object:

```
template<typename Lambda>
class Test
{
public:
    Test(Lambda _lambda):lambda(_lambda){}

    Lambda lambda;
};

int main()
{
    const auto lambda=[](double x){return x;};
    Test test=lambda;
    //print 1 1
    std::cout<<sizeof(lambda)<<" "<<sizeof(test)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not stored a single byte/ But yes, zero sized objects still request one byte for unique address.

Comment: anyhow, looking at the `sizeof` and object is not suffcient to know how expensive it is to copy an object. Consider a `int*` that points to an array of 10000000 doubles. To copy the array it is not sufficient to copy the pointer

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 `std::is_empty_v<decltype(Lambda)>`, and if you add `[[no_unique_address]]` to `Test`, `std::is_empty_v<decltype(test)>`: https://godbolt.org/z/d1sTcM (They are literally empty types with no state they could possibly copy). Also since the lambda is a trivial type, the size is the same as how expensive it is to copy, since copying is the same as `memcpy` (And copying an `int*` is just copying `sizeof(int*)` bytes)

Comment: @Artyer I am not saying that the answer is wrong, its just not convincing. Your comment is ;)